# JSON_ARRAY() creates a single element array instead of multiple

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to extract data from some tables, and after using `GROUP_CONCAT` with `QUOTE`, I'm trying to parse it into a JSON array using `JSON_ARRAY()`.

The problem is that it creates a single element array instead of expected multiple elements.

query:

```sql
set session group_concat_max_len = 65000;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS someTable
(VulnerabilityId VARCHAR(40), Versions TEXT, Manager VARCHAR(100), PackageName VARCHAR(400), INDEX temp_vulnerabilityId_index(VulnerabilityId)) AS
    (
        SELECT VulnerabilityId, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT QUOTE(vulnerabilityExtendedData.Version) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Versions, Manager, Name AS PackageName
        FROM (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM myTable pv
                 JOIN
                 (
                   SELECT Id, Version, Name, 'Mvn' AS Manager
                   FROM mvn
                 ) 
                 pkgManagers
                 ON pv.PackageId = pkgManagers.Id
             ) vulnerabilityExtendedData
        GROUP BY Id, Name, Manager
    );

SELECT JSON_ARRAY(CONVERT(Versions, CHAR(10000))) AS ARRAY, JSON_ARRAY(Versions AS ANOTHER_ARRAY, Versions
FROM someTable;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS someTable;
```

What's returned is:

| ARRAY | ANOTHER_ARRAY | Versions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["'1.6.1', '1.7'"] | ["'1.6.1', '1.7'"] | '1.6.1', '1.7' |

When using a simple query using the value from 'Versions' column:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY('1.6.1', '1.7')
```

I'm getting the expected result

```
["1.6.1", "1.7"]
```

I tried converting and casting 'Versions' to char, quoting and unquoting and couldn't produce the expected result.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you need? your expected array and the returned value both are a json array, not a single element array.

Comment: Show `someTable` content as INSERT INTO script, not as a query. Show desired output as formatted table (like for "but what's returned is"). Edit last SELECT (parenthesis balance).